# Delay javascript action with switch class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Okay so this is what I am wanting to do:

1. Switch the class from col-lg-12 to col-lg-6 of the div with an id of `info` with a slide effect
2. Slide Down the div with an id of `project` after the above action has completed.

Right now, 2 is happening along with 1 and not being delayed. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#project").hide();

    $("#phone").blur(function(){

        if($("#name").val() > ""){
            if($("#business").val() > ""){
                if($("#email").val() > ""){
                    if($("#phone").val() > ""){

                        $("#info").switchClass("col-lg-12", "col-lg-6", 500);
                        $("#project").slideDown(800).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 800 );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Does the class switch trigger a CSS animation or do you want to know how to do the animation in JS?

Comment: The animation works. That is not the issue, the issue is, the slideDown happens before the class switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious if something like this might be what you are looking for. A callback complete for the last effect in your chain which is the switchClass. Then do the chained functions after slide in etc.. . This way you are staging your operations as completed callbacks.

```
$("#info").switchClass("col-lg-12", "col-lg-6", 500, function(){
  $("#project").slideDown(800).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 800);
});
```

Edited to try and match your staging needs

Comment: This still performs the operations backwards. The switchClass needs to happen before the slideDown

Comment: Ha. Just needed to switch the actions in your answer. Do that and I will accept the answer! :)